# Uncaught TypeError: $container.masonry is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry, imagesloaded

I am having an issue with masonry images overlapping when the page loads.  In order to make the images layout properly I tried adding this code but still not working and getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: $container.masonry is not a function

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.1.8/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

   <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $container = $("#container");

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.masonry();
    });
});


<script>
        (function ($) {
            var $container = $('.masonry_wrapper'),
                colWidth = function () {
                    var w = $container.width(), 
                        columnNum = 1,
                        columnWidth = 0;
                    if (w > 1200) {
                        columnNum  = 4;
                    } else if (w > 900) {
                        columnNum  = 4;
                    } else if (w > 600) {
                        columnNum  = 2;
                    } else if (w > 300) {
                        columnNum  = 1;
                    }
                    columnWidth = Math.floor(w/columnNum);
                    $container.find('.item').each(function() {
                        var $item = $(this),
                            multiplier_w = $item.attr('class').match(/item-w(\d)/),
                            multiplier_h = $item.attr('class').match(/item-h(\d)/),
                            width = multiplier_w ? columnWidth*multiplier_w[1]-4 : columnWidth-4,
                            height = multiplier_h ? columnWidth*multiplier_h[1]*0.5-4 : columnWidth*0.5-4;
                        $item.css({
                            width: width,
                            height: height
                        });
                    });
                    return columnWidth;
                }

                function refreshWaypoints() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    }, 10200);   
                }

                $('nav.portfolio-filter ul a').on('click', function() {
                    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                    $container.isotope({ filter: selector }, refreshWaypoints());
                    $('nav.portfolio-filter ul a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    return false;
                });

                function setPortfolio() { 
                    setColumns();
                    $container.isotope('reLayout');
                }

                isotope = function () {
                    $container.isotope({
                        resizable: true,
                        itemSelector: '.item',
                        masonry: {
                            columnWidth: colWidth(),
                            gutterWidth: 0
                        }
                    });
                };
            isotope();
            $(window).smartresize(isotope);
        }(jQuery));
    </script>
```

Comment: Didi you include the masonry library file in your html?http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: yes it is included

Comment: You would better put jquery at the first. But i dont think that is the problem

Comment: moved jquery to the first and still have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of issues.

1. Your masonry code is not within a script tag
2. You are using both masonry and isotope in your code. Isotope.js has a masonry layout but it is not masonry.js. They are not used together. (You haven't loaded isotope.js anyway.) Masonry does not filter items, only isotope. Pick one to use and use the code for it
3. Your loading imagesloaded.js after masonry.js but you are calling the imagesloaded function before masonry in your code.
4. Your loading masonry.js before jquery.js but you are using jquery to load masonry.
5. You have 2 variables called $container

   var $container = $('.masonry_wrapper')

   var $container = $("#container");

Here is a basic code setup to at least load masonry:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.1.8/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var $container = $("#container");
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.masonry();
});
});
</script>
```

The rest of your code is for isotope.